# Problem related to Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Assuming there are 3 different types of objects, and the subtypes are identical, then how will we arrange them if no 2 can be together?

A specific example -

Let there be 4 red, 3 yellow and 2 green balls, then the total number of arrangements in a row such that no two balls of same colour are together (balls of same colour are identical) are?

Comment: This particular type of adjacency restriction question has some good answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976536/number-of-possible-permutations-of-n1-1s-n2-2s-n3-3s-n4-4s-such-that-no-t/2194358#2194358). I know for a fact that there are also several more like this on MSE but the one I have linked is the only one I could find.

Comment: Here is another [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569399/in-how-many-ways-can-3-red-3-blue-and-3-green-balls-be-arranged-so-that/2570350#2570350) involving three balls of each colour.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, I *knew* there were some more! Hadn't seen that one though (+1).

Comment: Look at the answer by ShreevatsaR to this question:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626500/permutations-and-combinations-pens-of-same-color/2627799#comment5427159_2627799