# Arranging finite balls of different color such that no balls of the same color are adjacent

Tags: combinatorics

The problem involves arranging balls of different color in a line such that no two balls of the same color are adjacent to each other. Eventually I would like to find a generalization of having $m$ different colors of balls and $n$ balls of each color, where each ball besides color are indistinguishable. But for now I will start with $3$ colors, red blue and yellow, and having $3$ of each color.

If we had an infinite number of each ball, then i know the answer would be $3(2^8)$ but this is including arrangements where we might only have red and blue balls alternating and not have any yellows.

One thought was to consider "grouping" the colors in its $3!$ permutations and finding the number of arrangements of the groups. But this wouldn't consider arrangements such as $RYRYBYBRB$

I feel like recurrence may be needed for a generalization but without being able to find this simple case I don't know if I can use it. Searching other questions of this sort doesn't help me either as it isn't this type of restriction.

Brute forcing it is one option but it seems like a mess even for this smaller case, so it would only be good for smaller cases.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try to state the problem in the question body (not just in the title). The balls are placed in a row or in a circle ?

Comment: Oh my I forgot to add that part. These are arranged in a straight line. Will edit

Comment: [This problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569399/in-how-many-ways-can-3-red-3-blue-and-3-green-balls-be-arranged-so-that/2570350#2570350) covers the cases of $3$ red, $3$ blue, and $3$ green balls arranged in a row so that two consecutive balls are of the same color.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig ... "so that _no_ two consecutive balls..." , no?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976536/number-of-possible-permutations-of-n1-1s-n2-2s-n3-3s-n4-4s-such-that-no-t/2194358#2194358) for possible solutions. I'm certain there are other answers elsewhere on MSE too.

Comment: @leonbloy Quite.