# In how many ways can letters in a word CALCULUS be rearranged so that no two identical letters are adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> In how many ways can letters in a word CALCULUS be rearranged so that no two identical letters are adjacent?

I’ve been thinking of Inclusion-Exclusion principle. Is there any different way to solve this task?

Comment: Inclusion-Exclusion should work fine. You have three letters which appear twice, so you will not get that many terms in the final expansion for the rearrangements.

Comment: I know but I wonder if there’s any other way to do that not using sophisticated methods

Comment: Not using sophisticated methods would force you to do tedious casework.

Comment: What would be the final answer then

Comment: If you want additional feedback, then you should [edit] your post to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank you! I will edit within a few hours

Comment: Have you made any progress?

Comment: I counted all the permutations: 7! but I’m not sure of the usage of inclusion-exclusion principle. There exists formula : sum from p=1 to n (-1)^(p-1) times n!/p! but don’t know how to apply it.

Comment: There are eight letters in CALCULUS, of which two are Cs, two are Ls, two are Us, one is a A, and one is an S.  If we did not have the restriction that no two adjacent letters may be the same, we could choose two of the eight positions for the Cs, two of the remaining six positions for the Ls, two of the remaining four positions for the Us, one of the remaining two positions for the A, and then fill the remaining position with the S.  We can do this is in $$\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1} = \frac{8!}{2!2!2!1!1!}$$ distinguishable ways.

Comment: My answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569399/in-how-many-ways-can-3-red-3-blue-and-3-green-balls-be-arranged-so-that/2570350#2570350) may help you understand how to apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to the problem you asked.

Comment: Any further progress?

Comment: I’m pretty busy right now, but I’ll try to get that next week.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $2220$

[image: CALCULUS automaton]
here is an automaton that generates CALCULUS-like words. To cover all possibilities, the S state must and suffice to be reached 5 to 8 times.

For each time, the generating function is

$$Z = (c+a+l+u+s - c^2 - l^2 - u^2)$$

where $+$ stands for inclusion, and $-$ for exclusion.

Now we take the coefficient of $c^2al^2u^2s$ in $Z^5+Z^6+Z^7+Z^8$ which is $2220$.

The explanation is that each occurence of a double letter in each word is generated twice, once with + and once with -. After summing, the terms containing double consecutive letters vanish.

There is no simpler method. If there were, the generating function would be simpler but that is not the case since I checked them all against the problems here.

Comment: This doesn't match my count; it should be $8!/(2!2!2!) = 7! = 5040$.

Comment: ? Hello, you forgot the exclusion : you took just $Z = (c+a+l+u+s )$

Comment: Oh, I see; the “no two identical letters adjacent”. Missed that. thanks.