# Arranging $3$ groups of people

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have $4$ Americans, $3$ Russians and $5$ Chinese. They are forming a line and no nationality is allowed to form a block. How many possibilities are there?

A block just means that something like $AA...$ isn't allowed.

We have $12!/4!3!5!$ possibilities if we allow blocks, now we have to substract  the possibilities with blocks. Let's take $2A$ and force them to be next to each other, we get $11$ possibilities; so $11(10!/2!3!5!)$. We have to do the same with $R$ and $C$ and we get

$12!/4!3!5! - 11(10!/2!3!5! + 10!/4!1!5! + 10!/4!3!3!)$. Is this correct?

I just used the $n!/k_1!k_2!...$ formula and don't really know where it comes from, can someone explain that maybe? And is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I just realized that my solution is negative, that's very unfortunate

Comment: $(k_1+k_2+\cdots k_n)!/ k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!$ is the multinomial coefficient, and counts distinguishable ways to arrange a multiset of $k_1$ identical items of type 1, $k_2$ identical items of type 2, et cetera.

Comment: I would look at it recursively, keeping track of which nationality starts.  It's easy with small groups and larger groups are made out of smaller ones.

Comment: So do just two of the same nationality side by side form a block? Or must it be all of them?

Comment: The length of the block doesn't matter, $...AA...$ and $...AAA...$ aren't allowed

Comment: Maybe the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569399/in-how-many-ways-can-3-red-3-blue-and-3-green-balls-be-arranged-so-that/2570350#2570350) can guide you in the right direction?

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that with conventional methods, it will be a very tortuous affair, so I shall use the formula by [Jair Taylor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129451/find-the-number-of-arrangements-of-k-mbox-1s-k-mbox-2s-cdots/129802#129802)

Define polynimomials $q_k(x) = \Large\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(-1)^{i-k}}{i!} {k-1 \choose i-1}x^i$ for $k\geq 1$, and $q_0(x) =1,$ e.g. for $k=2,q_2(x)$ works out to $(x2−2x)/2!$
The number of permutations will be given by

> $$\int_0^\infty \prod_j q_{k_j}(x)\,  e^{-x}\,dx.$$

The specific formula for this problem can be seen at [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%5B%281%2F%283%214%215%21%29%29%28x%5E3-6x%5E2%2B6x%29%28x%5E4-12x%5E3%2B36x%5E2-24x%29%28x%5E5-20x%5E4%2B120x%5E3-240x%5E2%2B120x%29e%5E-xdx%5D%2C+x+%3D+0+to+infinity) yielding the answer as $588$

This, of course, is if we don't care which particular persons are sitting next to each other, we are concerned only about two people of the same nationality not being together, as seems to be the intention.